# Get desired wspace and subplots appropriately sized?

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to make a plot with one panel up top (colspan = 2) and two plots below, with a controlled amount of space between them. I'd like the bounds of the plots to be in alignment. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
import cartopy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

gs = GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios=[2, 1], hspace=0, wspace=0)

ax0 = pyplot.subplot(gs[0, :], projection=cartopy.crs.LambertConformal())
ax0.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax0.set_extent([-120, -75, 20, 52], cartopy.crs.Geodetic())

ax1 = pyplot.subplot(gs[1, 0], projection=cartopy.crs.LambertConformal())
ax1.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax1.set_extent([-90, -75, 20, 30], cartopy.crs.Geodetic())

ax2 = pyplot.subplot(gs[1, 1], projection=cartopy.crs.LambertConformal())
ax2.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax2.set_extent([-90, -75, 20, 30], cartopy.crs.Geodetic())

pyplot.show()
```

[image: Poorly]

First problem is that the `wspace=0` parameter doesn't take.
Second problem is (at least this is my guess on how to proceed) calculating a height ratio that will make the width of the upper subplot equal the combined width of the lower subplots (plus any wspace).

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480113/force-aspect-ratio-for-a-map help at all?