# Cartopy: set extent for perfectly square map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, cartopy

Assume I need to plot a map with Cartopy and the resulting figure should have square dimensions. In my (simplistic) understanding, this should be easy using the [plate carrée projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection), since longitude and latitude are directly used as planar coordinates. This means I expect a square map if the extent covered by latitude and longitude are the same.

However, while the following code works if the extent starts at the equator (e.g. `[-120, -60, 0, 60]`), it fails for an extent apart from the equator. How does the extent have to be computed that the resulting map is a square? (I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340015/plot-square-cartopy-map), but it did not really help since the coordinate transformation only returned the given coordinates).

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[5, 5], subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=1.0, top=1.0)
ax.set_extent([-120, -60, 15, 75])
ax.stock_img()
fig.savefig('Test.pdf')
```

The following image shows the output, which unfortunately contains white borders at the vertical edges:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps related and helpful https://jdhao.github.io/2017/06/03/change-aspect-ratio-in-mpl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be a property of the chosen projection? You can see it happening when adding the transformation by inspecting the `ax._position`, `ax._originalPosition` attributes:

```
Bbox([[0.015576512213622107, 0.0], [0.9844234877863779, 1.0]])
Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]])
```

You can add `ax.set_adjustable('datalim')` to make it change the limits, instead of the box (of the axes) to fill the given extent. Note how this slightly changes the `ax.get_xlim()` & `ax.get_ylim()`, so make sure that's acceptable for your application.
I personally often explicitly add the dpi and bbox when saving, to make sure the output has the intended dimensions, see the example below.

When I use a different projection, I can get it to work straightaway, the code below produces a clean 500x500px image with only the axes visible in the output, not the red figure. So perhaps it's a property of the PlateCarree projection?

```py
map_proj = ccrs.Mercator()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100, facecolor="r",
    subplot_kw={'projection': map_proj},
)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=1.0, top=1.0)
ax.set_extent([-10000000, 10000000, -10000000, 10000000], crs=map_proj)
ax.coastlines()

fig.savefig('Test.png', bbox_inches=0, dpi=100)
```