# gridspec hspace leaving a big gap when using cartopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm making a figure with several subplots using GridSpec. Some of the subplots are maps, so I'm using Cartopy to plot them. When calling GridSpec, the parameter `wspace` works, but `hspace` still leaves a big gap between the subplots, even when setting `hspace=0`. This only happens if the subplots are with cartopy.

For example, using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2,2,wspace=0.05,hspace=0)
for k in range(0,4):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[k],projection=crs)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.coastlines()
```

produces:

[image: hspace is 0]

Larger values of `hspace` are not ignored (for instance, `hspace=5` works). I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480113/force-aspect-ratio-for-a-map) where on a similar problem they suggest to use `ax.set_aspect('auto')` or `ax.set_adjustable('datalim')`. In my case, both of them make `hspace` work for the small values. However, it deforms the shape of the original map:

[image: deformed map]

Any idea on how I could solve this, without deforming the map?

Using Python 3.7.6, Matplotlib 3.1.3, Cartopy 0.17.0

Comment: The aspect ratio of the subplots is fixed, and the size of the figure is fixed, so there will be blank space somewhere.  If you don't want so much blank space, make the figure smaller in the y-direction by adjusting height: `plt.figure(figsize=(width, height)`

Comment: @JodyKlymak This works, thanks! If you are willing to answer the question I'll mark it as solved.